# Cyclotomic fields and singular moduli

Tags: elliptic-curves, shimura-varieties, modular-forms, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mu$ be the roots of unity and $S$ be the image under the modular $j$-function of all imaginary quadratic $\tau$. Then what is $\mathbb{Q}(\mu)\cap\mathbb{Q}(S)$?

Comment: This is a subcase of: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15781/given-a-number-field-k-when-is-its-hilbert-class-field-an-abelian-extension-of

Comment: I think it isn't a subcase of that question, unless OP only wants elliptic curves with CM by the maximal order. Also, OP, do you want elliptic curves over Q, or over the algebraic closure of Q?

Comment: I think it is a subcase, but I'm not certain: I think the answer is, kind of written in the other thread, that the $j$-invariant is in $\mathbb{Q}^\text{cyc}$ if and only if the class group of the order is an elementary abelian 2-group. And I think he means over the closure, which is the same as over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully clear things up

Comment: It's not clear to me why this is a subcase. Could anyone please expand a little?

Comment: @Adam: the j-function on an imaginary quadratic irrational generates the ray class field of the smallest order containing the number. In particular, if the quadratic irrational generates the maximal order of an imaginary quadratic field then the ray class field is the Hilbert class field. By the Kronecker-Weber theorem, $\mathbb{Q}(\mu)=\mathbb{Q}^\text{ab}$, so asking if $j(\tau)\in\mathbb{Q}(\mu)$ is the same as asking if $\mathbb{Q}(j(\tau))/\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extension.

Comment: Standard references are Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$, and chapter 2 of Silverman's Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.